# MongoDB not connecting in Node.js App running on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose

i'm trying run my app on an ec2 instance. it throws an error everytime i start it. seems like its unable to connect to my mongodb database. i've installed mongoose and mongodb via npm.  i'm running mongodb on the same ec2 instance as the server. i've added a custom tcp rule to my ec2 security group to allow incoming traffic on port 27017.

can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? i've been trying to fix it for the last 3 hours.

here's my code for connecting to mongodb:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'app');
```

and here's the error i keep receiving:

```
ubuntu@:~/app$ node app.js
   info  - socket.io started
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Express server listening on port 8080

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/polls/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Can you try giving the IP address instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm won't actually install the mongo server for you, so make sure that it's installed and running.

To verify that it is running, as the root user on your instance:

```
service mongod status
```

Next, verify that you can connect to it:

```
mongo
> show dbs
```

I suspect that if you can get to this point, your application will work.

Comment: well...that's embarassing.